# Globe draped layer updating - ArcObjects vs Desktop

Tags: arcglobe

I have a globe document that includes several layers that are draped on the globe's surface, but no elevation layers. If I open the document in ArcGlobe (desktop) and add an elevation layer, the appearanceof the draped layers changes - they are draped on the elevation. However, if I use this same globe document in a Visual Studio application and add the elevation layer programmatically, the appearance of the draped layers doesn't change. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Here's the code I'm using to add the elevation layer programmatically:

IGlobe theGlobe = axGlobeControl1.Globe;
 IRasterLayer mergedElevLyr = new RasterLayerClass();
 mergedElevLyr.CreateFromFilePath("D:\@ALPACAS\AlpacasCT\experimental\3D\data\MergedElev_111711.img");
 mergedElevLyr.Visible = false;
 theGlobe.AddLayerType((ILayer)mergedElevLyr, esriGlobeLayerType.esriGlobeLayerTypeElevation, true);
 theGlobe.GlobeDisplay.RefreshViewers();

Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Mark